# How do I run a `/usr/sbin/` binary in cron?

Tags: crontab

As root I added used `crontab -e` to add my script. However the script uses a binary in `/usr/sbin/` and I get an error about it not existing when the script runs from cron. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should just use the full path for the binary.

So let’s say you wanted to use `ipconfig` in a cron job. Instead of your crontab having a command like this:

```
ipconfig
```

You would change that to be:

```
/usr/sbin/ipconfig
```

Remember: Shell paths just tell the system where to look for binaries/executables when you call them from the command line to make your life typing commands easier. Providing the full path for binaries/executables works 100% the same for script use.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not the cleanest approach, but

You can set PATH variable in crontab, put this as the first line of your crontab

```
# start of crontab file
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

# your cron entries below
```